# Get device id in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deviceid

how to get device id in react native. I am using create react native not android studio. I am new to this.

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
   this.state = { id: '' }
   this.onNavigateTo = this.onNavigateTo.bind(this);   
}
componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({id: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()}, () =>      
   alert(this.state.id));
}
render() {
  return (
       <Text>{this.state.id}</Text>
  );
}
```

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNDevice.uniqueId')

Note:- I am not using run-android or run-ios

I am using Create-react-native app and yarn start. The output will be on device through Expo app

Comment: Did you run the `link` command?

Comment: yes step : 1 npm install --save react-native-device-info                                       step : 2 react-native link react-native-device-info

Comment: Have you tried to clean the yarn cache? Not sure if it would help, but people are saying if they run `react-native run-ios` again, it would fix the issue, since you are doing yarn, maybe try that as well..

Comment: yeah lemme try !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: nope not working ??

Comment: :( Just try completely stop your launcher, reset cache, link and build. It feels like if you keep playing with it eventually you will get it work, btw the thread is here https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/137

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot use library that use native code with expo see [caveats](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#caveats) if you want to use native code you need to create your project with native code at getting started [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#getting-started) basically

1. install pre request apps (node - Java Development Kit - android studio - xcode - react native cli )
2. run command `react-native init MyProjectName`
3. cd your project folder `cd MyProjectName`
4. run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`

if you want to convert expo project to native code project you can do [ejecting-from-create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app)

1. install native code requirement as above
2. run `npm run eject`

after that you can use third party libraries that use native code and run `react-native link`

Comment: for me its building successfully but in device telling me the same problem

Comment: i am getting but i can get the ID only after build

Answer (score 17):

Instead of expo you can create a project using react-native CLI.

Create a new project using command :

```
react-native init Myproject

cd Myproject
```

Run the project using the following command :

```
react-native run-android
```

Then you can use react-native-device-info package.

I tried with following versions and it worked for me.

```
  "react": "16.0.0",
  "react-native": "0.50.4",
  "react-native-device-info": "^0.12.1",
```

I installed it with command :

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

Then I link it with command :

```
react-native link react-native-device-info
```

If you are facing any issue while linking the package then you can do the manual link or you can cross check the packages is successfully link or not.

1. in android/app/build.gradle:

> ```
>  dependencies {
>         ...
>         compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
>     +   compile project(':react-native-device-info')
>     }
> ```

2. in android/settings.gradle:

> ...
>
> include ':app'
>
> include ':react-native-device-info'
>
> project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,
>   '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')

3. in MainApplication.java:

> ```
> + import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
>
>   public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
>     //......
>
>     @Override
>     protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
>       return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
> +         new RNDeviceInfo(),
>           new MainReactPackage()
>       );
>     }
>
>     ......
>   }
> ```

**Permissions**

Add the appropriate, optional permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>         <!-- for Device Name -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>  <!-- for Phone Number -->
```

**Example**

```
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
// or import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

var deviceId = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();
```

you can use above deviceId.

Comment: Note: getUniqueID may not return a real unique id for the device. According to documentation it returns the ANDROID_ID variable from the SDK, where this value can change on rooted phones, factory resets, or even just in general (manufacturers have reported the same id for 2 different phones from 2 different manufacturers)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Expo try this.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
this.clientId = Constants.deviceId;
```

Comment: This will not work on expo SDK 44

Comment: `deviceId` was deleted 'expo-constants' from in the recent versions of Expo. Don't know why they did this.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to get a client unique ID, then you might want to use `NativeModules`.

`Import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'`

on your component...

for iOS:  `console.log(NativeModules.SettingsManager.clientUniqueId)`
for Android: `console.log(NativeModules.PlatformConstants.fingerprint);` (or `NativeModules.PlatformConstants.serial`)

Comment: NativeModules.SettingsManager.clientUniqueId returns undefined

Comment: Api might have changed (as they always do) or something might be wrong, console.log(NativeModules.SettingsManager) so you can know the options

Answer (score -1):

getUniqueId is not reliable on Android using react-native-device-info, see the issue below:
 - https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/355

There is a PR waiting to be released:
 - https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/pull/358

After releasing this change, you can get the unique id using getUUID